# Compatibility spring-batch / spring / hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-batch

I have evolved versions in my application (for example hibernate 3.2.6.ga >> 5.1.0.Final), and since then I have an error when launching my spring batch job:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You can't operate on a closed Connection!!!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.commit(NewProxyConnection.java:809)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.commit(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.commit(NewProxyConnection.java:803)
    ... 17 more
```

Versions are :

- hibernate 5.1.0.Final
- spring 3.1.0.RELEASE
- spring-batch  2.0.0.M3
- c3p0 0.9.1.2

Is the problem the spring batch version ?

Comment: Spring 3 doesn't support hibernate 5.1. Also why are you using a milestone release of Spring Batch instead of a final release?

Comment: I take an application that is not mine, I'm trying to correct these problems. Which version of spring-batch do you recommend with spring 3.1.0.RELEASE ?

Comment: Anything that has `.RELEASE` in it and not `.M` or `.RC` those are beta/pre-release versions. As stated hibernate 5 isn't supported on Spring 3.1 you can go as far as hibernate 4.

Comment: Why are you using Spring Batch 2?  That also won't support many of the versions you're looking at.